# How to schedule automatic backups in teamcity?

Tags: backup, teamcity, schedule

We are using Teamcity 6.5.6 professional version, which gives me the option to run a backup but I do not see any option to schedule it to a particular time.

I am not sure if this version of teamcity even supports scheduled backups. If it is not possible through teamcity GUI, I wonder if there is any other option?

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980461/python-rest-teamcity-backup = working Python code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin) to run the backup. We actually use TeamCity to run a scheduled build at midnight each day. That build makes a call to the rest api to do the backup.

Comment: Thanks.The REST API says I should make a POST request to my teamcity server with all the parameters required. If I set up a build for this in teamcity, what type of build runner I should use?

Comment: @kranthi - we wrote a simple python script and use the command line runner. Any scripting language will do.

Comment: Thanks to this suggestion I was able to build a solution based on the REST API. The source-code is hosted on github and here is a blog post describing how it workds: http://daniellang.net/how-to-automate-teamcity-backups-using-its-rest-api/

Answer (score 20):

I wrote [Powershell script for TeamCity auto backups](http://ileonenko.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/automatic-teamcity-backup-with-powershell/), which you can schedule and run backup.

Here's the code:

```
function Execute-HTTPPostCommand() {
    param(
        [string] $url,
        [string] $username,
        [string] $password
    )

    $authInfo = $username + ":" + $password
    $authInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($authInfo))

    $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $webRequest.ContentType = "text/html"
    $PostStr = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes("")
    $webrequest.ContentLength = $PostStr.Length
    $webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + $authInfo
    $webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true
    $webRequest.Method = "POST"

    $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
    $requestStream.Write($PostStr, 0, $PostStr.length)
    $requestStream.Close()

    [System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
    $rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
    [System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
    [string] $results = $sr.ReadToEnd();

    return $results;
}

function Execute-TeamCityBackup() {
    param(
        [string] $server,
        [string] $addTimestamp,
        [string] $includeConfigs,
        [string] $includeDatabase,
        [string] $includeBuildLogs,
        [string] $includePersonalChanges,
        [string] $fileName
    )
    $TeamCityURL = [System.String]::Format("{0}/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup?addTimestamp={1}&includeConfigs={2}&includeDatabase={3}&includeBuildLogs={4}&includePersonalChanges={5}&fileName={6}",
                                            $server,
                                            $addTimestamp,
                                            $includeConfigs,
                                            $includeDatabase,
                                            $includeBuildLogs,
                                            $includePersonalChanges,
                                            $fileName);

    Execute-HTTPPostCommand $TeamCityURL "USER" "PASSWORD"
}

$server = "http://YOUR_SERVER"
$addTimestamp = $true
$includeConfigs = $true
$includeDatabase = $true
$includeBuildLogs = $true
$includePersonalChanges = $true
$fileName = "TeamCity_Backup_"

Execute-TeamCityBackup $server $addTimestamp $includeConfigs $includeDatabase $includeBuildLogs $includePersonalChanges $fileName
```

Comment: Where does the zip file go?

Comment: @PaulZahra, by default backup files are created in <TeamCity Data Directory>/backup  And here's a link how to find it https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/TeamCity+Data+Directory

Comment: @IvanLeonenko By the way... just found your script here... this may interest you (it has some minor changes)... https://blogs.endjin.com/2013/08/a-step-by-step-guide-to-automating-teamcity-backups/

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to write programs to perform your task, simply run this command:

```
wget --user=*** --password=*** "http://localhost:8085/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup?includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=true&fileName=ScheduledBackup-" --post-data=
```

where stars should be replaced with your TeamCity login information.

On Windows, you can get WGET as a part of Cygwin package

Comment: `wget` is also included in [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) if you want a lighter-weight option than Cygwin. Get both the [unxutils.zip](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/UnxUtils.zip) and [unxupdates.zip](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/UnxUpdates.zip); unzip the utils, unzip the updates, move the updates into the `usr/local/wbin` folder for unxutils and then register it on your $PATH.

Comment: For anyone using UnxUtils: the `--user`, `--password` and `--post-data` parameters aren't accepted by WGET (I don't know if they are in the actual Unix WGET or not). Try using `--http-user` and `--http-passwd`. Didn't find a replacement for `--post-data` in the wget help from UnxUtils. Also, where does the resulting file go??

Answer (score 8):

For those who wants to trigger builds from Mac OS (use "command line" runner on TeamCity):

```
curl --basic --user user:password -X POST "http://team.city.server:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup?includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=true&fileName=ScheduledBackup"
```

Comment: `curl` should be an option for *(just about?)* any OS. On Windows, you can get ith through [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) which uses MinGW(http://www.mingw.org/), if you let it install the Git commands for all command prompts, making this a candidate for everyone. Also, according to the manual, `curl` defaults to basic auth mode so you can probably drop `--basic` if keeping the command simple. YMMV so test it out on your OS.

Answer (score 7):

We run maintainDB.cmd and schedule it with the Windows Task Scheduler, it's a one line command and requires no extra software. maintainDB is fully documented in the TeamCity documentation.

Comment: maintainDB requires the TeamCity service to be stopped in order to use it, but it is possible to stop and start the service from the command line

Comment: This is (imo) by far the best answer, mainly because it does not require keeping user/password and becuase it uses a super simple built-in tool

Comment: This is the best solution, but it does not work for us. After calling maintainDB from the command line, it exits our batch script and so the start commands never get called.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the environment variable to have the team city server address resolve at build time:

```
curl --basic --user user:pasword -X POST "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup?includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=true&fileName=ScheduledBackup"
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @Ivan Leonenko script I added some lines of code to wait that the backup ends before exit.

```
function Execute-HTTPCommand() {
    param(
        [string] $method,
        [string] $url,
        [string] $username,
        [string] $password
    )

    $authInfo = $username + ":" + $password
    $authInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($authInfo))

    $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $webRequest.ContentType = "text/html"
    $PostStr = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes("")
    $webrequest.ContentLength = $PostStr.Length
    $webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + $authInfo
    $webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true
    $webRequest.Method = $method

    if ($method -ne "GET")
    {
        $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
        $requestStream.Write($PostStr, 0, $PostStr.length)
        $requestStream.Close()
    }

    [System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
    $rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
    [System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
    [string] $results = $sr.ReadToEnd();

    return $results;
}

function Execute-TeamCityBackup() {
    param(
        [string] $server,
        [string] $addTimestamp,
        [string] $includeConfigs,
        [string] $includeDatabase,
        [string] $includeBuildLogs,
        [string] $includePersonalChanges,
        [string] $fileName,
        [string] $username,
        [string] $password
    )
    $TeamCityURL = [System.String]::Format("{0}/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup?addTimestamp={1}&includeConfigs={2}&includeDatabase={3}&includeBuildLogs={4}&includePersonalChanges={5}&fileName={6}",
                                            $server,
                                            $addTimestamp,
                                            $includeConfigs,
                                            $includeDatabase,
                                            $includeBuildLogs,
                                            $includePersonalChanges,
                                            $fileName);

    Write-Host "Starting TeamCity backup"

    Execute-HTTPCommand "POST" $TeamCityURL $username $password
}

function Wait-TeamCityBackup() {
    param(
        [string] $server,
        [string] $username,
        [string] $password
    )

    $GetBackupStatusUrl = [System.String]::Format("{0}/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup",
                                            $server);

    do {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        $backupStatus = Execute-HTTPCommand "GET" $GetBackupStatusUrl $username $password
        Write-Host $backupStatus
    } while ($backupStatus -eq 'Running')

}


$server = "http://YOUR_SERVER"
$addTimestamp = $true
$includeConfigs = $true
$includeDatabase = $true
$includeBuildLogs = $true
$includePersonalChanges = $true
$fileName = "TeamCity_Backup_"
$username = "USERNAME" # Must be a TeamCity Admin
$password = "PASSWORD"

Execute-TeamCityBackup $server $addTimestamp $includeConfigs $includeDatabase $includeBuildLogs $includePersonalChanges $fileName $username $password
Wait-TeamCityBackup $server $username $password
```